# Pass character stream to libxml2

Tags: c++, c, xml, libxml2

I have a XML document which is received as a character stream. I wish to parse this using libxml2. Well one way would be to save it as an .xml and then open it using one of the libxml2 API's. Is there a way i can directly build a tree on this stream and parse it ?

Env is purely c++/c.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xlmCtxtReadFd](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCtxtReadFd) from parser.h. There's also [xmlCtxtReadMemory](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCtxtReadMemory), if you would rather use a block of memory than a stream.

Comment: Thanks , xmlCtxtReadMemory looks more like what i can use... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [xmlCtxtReadFd](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCtxtReadFd) or [xmlCtxtReadIO](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCtxtReadIO) depending on your context.